# How to find Population proportion confidence interval when n*p is less than 5?

Tags: proportion, population

I have been searching everywhere but haven't found any explicit information about this.
I have a total sample size of 15 weeks but only 3 of those weeks have the result i want. So p=3/15

But if I want to find a confidence interval for that, I checked n*p=15*3/15=3 which is less than 5. How would I be able to find the confidence interval of the population proportion?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you do when $np ≥ 5$. You can use [standard methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) such as the Jeffreys interval or the Wilson score interval. The method based on a normal approximation is worse with smaller sample sizes, but there's no reason to use it even for larger samples, because the use of a normal approximation necessarily reduces accuracy.